# Conky Display Problem Showing the horizontal half of info not the full info

Tags: conky

I have a strange problem with CONKY:

Just the horizontal half of information that is visible on my desktop (the horizontal half of time and date but the hard disks infos indicated in the config file are not)
Like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LBdu.png]

I use Ubuntu 12.10 with gnome-shell desktop

Can you help me please?

This is my Conky Config:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5633979/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please upload your conky script at http://paste.ubuntu.com/ . Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added the conky config in the message. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Locate your conky file.

2.Find **draw_borders no** and change to **draw_borders yes**

Above step is perform to get your conky size.

3.Locate minimum_size 500 200 and change the number.

**500 200 represent width and height** .

If you satisfied with the output, change back **draw_borders yes** to **draw_borders no**

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you **Penreturn** for your _detailed response_, and the `draw_borders yes` trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot Penreturn :).
I made some changes in the config file with 2 variables as in this code http://paste.ubuntu.com/5634151/ :
**minimum_size 250 350** #line 8 - **maximum_width 1024** #line 10
and returned this value -> **${voffset 10}** to the beginning of **line 52** of the code.

AND the results are successful :

[image]

Just I must indicate that I maked some changes before this, but results were chaotic with same values x). Thanks Penreturn :)

Is it a good idea to put **maximum_width** to **1024** ?

Comment: maximum_width to 1024 : my answer is no unless your conky cover all 1024 of size.

Comment: Thanks. I put it to 500 with no problems :). By the way your wallpaper is beautifull.